# Return sorted object base on its attributes

Tags: java

Not sure how to title it correctly but here goes.

I have a class `Plane` that creates an array of class `PlaneSeat`. 12 objects in my case

`PlaneSeat` has attributes `int seatId`, `int customerId`, `boolean assigned`.

I am trying to write a method for the `Plane` class that will return an array of `PlaneSeat` objects sorted by `customerId`.

This is what I have currently done up with. Right now I will return void as I have yet to prepare the correct data to construct the new `PlaneSeat`. The issue right now is, my algorithm is only comparing between the neighboring elements. Not sure what kind of in-build function I can use to achieve my wanted result?

I have looked at [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property), and while it is a comparable method it will modify the original data order, which I do not want. I just want to get an independent sorted set and return it without modifying the original order.

```
private void sortSeats()
    {
        int temp;
        Integer[] seatIdArray = new Integer[12];
        Integer[] custIdArray = new Integer[12];
        System.out.println("Inside sortSeats(), length =  " + seatIdArray.length);
        int count = 0;
        // prepare data
        for (int i = 0; i<seat.length;i++)
        {
            if (seat[i].isOccupied())
            {
                seatIdArray[count] = seat[i].getSeatID();
                custIdArray[count] = seat[i].getCustomerID();
                count ++;
            }
        }
        // sorting according to customerID
        for (int i = 1; i <seatIdArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (seatIdArray[i] == null) break;
            if (custIdArray[i-1] > custIdArray[i])
            {
                temp = custIdArray[i];
                custIdArray[i] = custIdArray[i-1];
                custIdArray[i-1] = temp;

                temp = seatIdArray[i];
                seatIdArray[i] = seatIdArray[i-1];
                seatIdArray[i-1] = temp;
            }
        }
        // displaying result
        for (int i = 0; i <seatIdArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (seatIdArray[i] == null) break;
            System.out.println("SeatID " + seatIdArray[i] + " assigned to CustomerID " + custIdArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property. This question was answered multiple times already.

Comment: Yes, `your algorithm is only comparing between the neighboring elements`. You might want to look into the working of sorting algorithms like bubble or insertion sort.